# terraform iterating over list of objects

Tags: terraform

I have map of object variable I am iterating over, that works as expected but I thought I could do it better.
What I have at the moment is:

```
variable "channel_list" {
  type        = map(object({
    channel   = string
  }))
  default = {
    "1" = {
      channel = "#channel1"
    }
}

resource "grafana_contact_point" "contact_point" {
  for_each         = var.channel_list
  name             = trim(each.value["channel"], "#")
  slack {
    ...
    recipient = each.value["channel"]
    username  = "xy"
  }
}

resource "grafana_notification_policy" "slack_notification_policy" {
  group_by      = ["..."]
  contact_point = grafana_contact_point.contact_point_unmatched.name
  policy {
    matcher {
      label = "x"
      match = "=~"
      value = ".*"
    }
    contact_point   = var.env == "production" ? "prod" : "non-prod"
    group_by        = ["..."]
  }
```

As I said it works well but I have a module split between two environments and I'd like to remove static values from `contact_point` in `grafana_notification_policy` resource. So I modified variable to list of objects:

```
variable "channel_list" {
  type        = list(object({
    one-name       = string
    another-name   = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      "one-name"     = "#channel1",
      "another-name" = "#channel2",
}
```

as well as turned policy block in `grafana_notification_policy` to dynamic:

```
  dynamic "policy" {
    for_each = var.channel_list
    content {
      matcher {
        label = "x"
        match = "=~"
        value = ".*"
      }
      contact_point = lookup(policy.value, "one-name", var.channel_list)
    }
  }
```

What I am not sure about is how to make `grafana_contact_point` resource working with this.

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: Are the `"one-name"` and `"another-name"` related to the `env` variable in some way? If so, then it can be made to work more "dynamically".

Comment: @MarkoE The problem I have is I don't how to trim over each of `one-name`,`another-name`,`yet-another-name` keys in `grafana_contact_point` resource

Comment: Any reason to move from a map to a list? The end goal is to have a policy for each of the channels in the same `grafana_contact_point`  resource or you want to have multiple `grafana_contact_point` resources?

Comment: multiple `grafana_contact_point`

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't understand that from the question because my focus was on a different resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way of achieving what you want. The variable you are using could be defined as:

```
variable "channel_list" {
  type = map(string)

  default = {
    "one-name"     = "#channel1",
    "another-name" = "#channel2",
  }
}
```

Then, the resource can use `for_each` without any issues:

```
resource "grafana_contact_point" "contact_point" {
  for_each         = var.channel_list
  name             = trim(each.value, "#")
  slack {
    ...
    recipient = each.value
    username  = "xy"
  }
}
```